# proving that a given asymmetric matrix $A$ has real eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have the following matrix $A$:

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
 -2K_1&  2K_1&     0&       0&                       0&                0&     0&     0&     0\\
    K_1& -2K_1&    K_1&       0&                       0&                0&     0&     0&     0\\
     0&    K_1& -2K_1&      K_1&                       0&                0&     0&     0&     0\\
     0&     0&    K_1&   -2K_1&                      K_1&                0&     0&     0&     0\\
     0&     0&     0& 2K_1v_r& -2K_1v_r(Q_rl_rw_r + 1)& 2K_1Q_rl_rv_rw_r&     0&     0&     0\\
     0&     0&     0&       0&                      K_2&            -2K_2&    K_2&     0&     0\\
     0&     0&     0&       0&                       0&               K_2& -2K_2&    K_2&     0\\
     0&     0&     0&       0&                       0&                0&    K_2& -2K_2&    K_2\\
     0&     0&     0&       0&                       0&                0&     0&  2K_2& -2K_2\\
\end{array} \right]
$$

where all variables $K_1$, $K_2$, $Q_r$, $w_r$, $l_r$ and $v_r$ are real and positive, $K_2 = K_1Q_rl_r^2$ and $v_r = l_r/(l_r+w_r)$. From the structure of the matrix, it is clear that all its eigenvalues are nonpositive with at least one eigenvalue at 0 ($Az=0$ with $z$ being a vector of ones or a multiple thereof).

My question is: Is there a way to prove that all eigenvalues of this matrix $A$ are real? If not, is there a counter example?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matrix has all real eigenvalues because it is similar to a real symmetric matrix: $D A D^{-1}$ is symmetric, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries
$$ \sqrt {{\frac {{\it K_2}}{{\it K_1}\,{\it Q_r}\,{\it l_r}\,{\it 
w_r}}}},\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\frac {{\it K_2}}{{\it K_1}\,{\it Q_r}\,{
\it l_r}\,{\it w_r}}}},\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\frac {{\it K_2}}{{\it K_1
}\,{\it Q_r}\,{\it l_r}\,{\it w_r}}}},\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\frac {{\it 
K_2}}{{\it K_1}\,{\it Q_r}\,{\it l_r}\,{\it w_r}}}},\sqrt {{
\frac {{\it K_2}}{{\it K_1}\,{\it Q_r}\,{\it l_r}\,{\it v_r}\,{
\it w_r}}}},\sqrt {2},\sqrt {2},\sqrt {2},1
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any reference for this? I mean any theorem/lemma that could help generalizing it?